# Message ! Argument of \enit@refstar@i has an extra }. with enumitem

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am using the enumerate environment with the enumitem package. The command

```
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\arabic]
```

gives me the error message

```
! Argument of \enit@refstar@i has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.222 \begin{enumerate}[ref=\arabic]
```

I actually wanted

```
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\fbox\arabic]
```

The answer from Alan Munn resolved my problem. The \arabic command has a mandatory parameter; either a counter name or a star.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a compilable (even with error) complete document.

Answer (score 3):

The numbering method macros for specifiying labels and refs in `enumitem` are suffixed with an asterisk: `\arabic*`, `\roman*`, `\alph*`, etc.  So to do what you want you need you can do something like the following. I've given a different `label` specification just as an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),ref=\fbox{\arabic*}]
\item Foo \label{foo}
\item Bar
\end{enumerate}
\ref{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]